# ASP.NET - Check if a WebControl contains server blocks?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Is there a way in code to determine if a Web control contains server blocks (other than, for example, parsing out the file, grabbing the contents of the tag, and scanning for `<% ... %>`)?

My reason for wanting this is because I have a **lot** of old Web forms that were designed without any regard whatsoever to HTML conformance. The header control (which is included on every page but is inside the `body` tag) contains the `link` tag referencing the site's main stylesheet. As long as the page's `head` tag does not contain server blocks, I can programmatically insert the `link` tag into `Page.Controls.OfType(Of HtmlHead).First()`, then set the visibility of the "bad" `link` tag to `false`.

Again, this is all legacy stuff (it's in 3.5 now, but most was written in the .NET 1.1 days), so changing everything over to use a master page is something for which I simply do not have the time and budget. Regardless, it would be nice to see the pages come up with the stylesheet pre-loaded, rather than having the browser begin rendering with no styling, then applying the stylesheet once it reaches the reference to it in the body.

Comment: Not elegant or efficient, but you could wrap it in a try/catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Mufasa entered his response as a comment, this question has been sitting unresolved too long. Therefore, I will surmise that the only solution is his -- to wrap it in a try/catch black.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a silly work around but could you change the name of your CSS file so that when the legacy code goes to load, it can't find it?